# How does the Malaysian Transit Pass work for Indian citizens?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia, kul

Quoting from [Ministry of Foreign Affairs- FAQ](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_chennai/faqs)

> Please check whether you are eligible for Transit Visa / Pass or not.
> The following are conditions for the said visa / pass:
>
> (i)         Indian visitor(s) who enter / depart to / from the country from Kuala Lumpur International Airport (KLIA) and Low Cost Carrier Terminal (LCCT)  only;
>
> (ii)         Visitor must possess a valid visa (Single Entry / Multiple Entry) from the destination country (only Australia, U.S.A., China, Japan, South Korea, New Zealand and Taiwan);
>
> (iii)        Visitor must possess a valid passport / travel document with an expiry date of not less than 6 months on the date of visit;
>
> (iv)        Visitor is not listed among those barred from entering Malaysia;
>
> (v)         Visitor must be in possession of a confirmed ticket to a third country;
>
> (vi)        Visitor must be able to finance his/her stay in Malaysia;
>
> (vii)       Visitor MUST visit the country in group (package tour) and the trip is either a packaged tour in Malaysia or in the
> destination country; and

We are a group of 3. 2 of us will hold a tourist visa from the destination country(Japan) and one with a residence card. Are we eligible for the Transit Pass?

However What does the point (vii) mean group (package tour)? should this also contain accommodation (Hotel). My plan was to book an accommodation myself and visit places on my own?

Also point (vi) how are we suppose to prove our finances? As it simply states must be able to finance.

Edit: I am planning to book a ticket in such a way that I can spend 24 hrs in KUL and fly to Tokyo. A night in the hotel and day to visit places. I will be booking my tickets in Malaysia Airlines

Comment: A "group (package tour)" means you've purchased an entire group tour package, generally with a guide, transportation, and accommodation, such as where a tour guide takes a bus full of people around. What is your travel plan exactly for this trip? If you read farther down that page, you don't need a transit visa at all if you're not going to leave the terminal and you're not flying Air Asia out of the Low Cost Carrier Terminal (if you are flying Air Asia, contact them to see if you can get TWOV on a single ticket).

Comment: Edited.! I am indeed planning to go out. So ideally i should be booking a guided tour?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to apply for a tourist visa to visit Malaysia. Based on [this page](http://www.airasia.com/sa/en/latest-news/malaysia-entry-requirement.page), the member of your party with a residency card in Japan may not need one. A packaged tour generally implies more than just hiring a guide, but means a complete tour package, as in an entire vacation package you buy at once.

Comment: Yes i saw that one too, But doesnt state the same on KLN website. Strange isnt it? ]

Comment: Transit visa means a visit on the way to another destination. so complicated regarding the tour package. IMHO :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the Transit pass without any fuss. All i need to do was produce my resident card/ visitor visa, boarding pass to Tokyo and a form given by the Transit pass office. I was given transit pass for five days. No package tour nothing was asked. The website is so confusing.

You just need to have transit for more than 5-6 hours and travel by AirAsia or Malaysian. Thats it.

Comment: Is Transit pass also available for codeshared flight connecting journey? (For example, flight operated by China airlines but codeshared with Malaysian airlines)

Comment: I am not sure about that. But in my guess it isnt acceptable i believe. "TWOV cannot be offered to passenger sponsored by airlines other than Malaysia Airlines, Air Asia and Malindo Air. At present only these 3 airlines have agreed and accepted all terms and conditions imposed by the Malaysian Government. " http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_new-delhi/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa?redirect=%2Fweb%2Find_new-delhi%2Fother_information See Point5